# Is it possible to make UIWebView load a html string but act like a UILabel

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, uilabel, ttstyledtextlabel

`TTStyledTextLabel` is exactly what I want, but I don't want to add all Three20 project just for this only one function.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with limiting the application to iOS 6+, Attributed string support is available on all standard rendering controls, if not, there are many other 3rd party solutions available (including my favorite, [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel)).  Just don't use a WebView for something this simple, they are really really heavy objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you may use [– stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a)

Say you load this string to webView:

```
<div id="msg">
    Super inner html with <b>bold</b>
</div>
```

Then you may get `msg`'s inner html like this:

```
NSString* value = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML"];
```

And set `msg`'s inner html like this:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = '%@'", newValue]];
```

Comment: Wait, how does executing javascript make a web view act like a label?

Comment: You may set and get container's html via javascript. That means you can put any html to webView and then retreive it. If you need examples I may give you some.

Comment: I still confused. How can you make UIWebView both unable to zoom and scrollable by javascript?

Comment: That's the other thing to achieve=) You may do this in different ways, that depends, you may just set `userInteracitonEnabled` to NO and `scalesPageToFit` to NO. There are different little things about that, but it depends. And note `CodaFi`'s answer, webViews are really heavy.

Comment: seems OHAttributedLabel is a good choice. I will give it a try.